# Как выраванить таблицы html

Tags: html, css, таблицы

У меня есть две таблицы сделанные с помощью html и css. Однако мне не нравится то, что таблицы находятся не на одном уровне. Хотелось бы, чтобы вторая таблица начиналась сверху, а не снизу. Как это сделать?

Код:

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black
}

table {
  width: 300px;

  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Тип Бетона
        </td>

        <td>
          Цена за 1м2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором
      </td>
      <td>
        2800р
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором
      </td>
      <td>
        2900р
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором
      </td>
      <td>
        3100р
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8
      </td>
      <td>
        3400р
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8
      </td>
      <td>
        3600р
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8
      </td>
      <td>
        3800р
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Тип Песка
        </td>

        <td>
          Цена за тонну
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Песок
      </td>
      <td>
        1100р
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал обёртку и задал стиль флексов:

```css
.tables-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  
  align-items: flex-start;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black
}

table {
  
 /* max-width: 300px;*/
 /* display: inline-block;*/
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Бетона
          </td>

          <td>
            Цена за 1м2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          2800р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          2900р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          3100р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          3400р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          3600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          3800р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Песка
          </td>

          <td>
            Цена за тонну
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Песок
        </td>
        <td>
          1100р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```